# Generating a sequence of values

Tags: mysql

How can I change 2,2,2,1,2 into 201,202,203,101,204 in MySQL?

I have a table with data in the format of:

```
+---+---+---+
| U | C | R |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
```

I am looking for a query to turn it into:

```
+---+-----+---+
| 1 | 201 | 1 |
| 1 | 202 | 2 |
| 1 | 203 | 3 |
| 1 | 101 | 4 |
| 1 | 204 | 5 |
+---+-----+---+
```

I have a query that is sort of what I am looking for:

```
SELECT U , C , group_concat( R ORDER BY R )
FROM table
GROUP BY U, C
```

But this is what I get back:

```
U-C-R
1-1-1, 2, 3, 5
1-2-4
```

Comment: `U` and `R` are irrelevant to the problem, correct?

Comment: Correct. They are just the column names.

Answer (score 1):

With MyISAM, you can get an AUTO_INCREMENT that starts over with each new value.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    C INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    N INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(C,N)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO foo (C)
    SELECT C FROM your_table;
```

Then...

```
SELECT 100*C + N FROM foo
```

gives you the desired numbers.  (If you need `U` and `R`, add them to `foo`, etc.)

If this is a 1-time task, then give that a try.  If you need the numbering to be on-going, then it gets messier.